# For loop to convert variables to Date format

Tags: r, date, for-loop, reference

I have two data frames of identical dimensions and column names. 
I want on both convert the dates stored currently as characters to dates. Is there any way to automate this using a for loop? I though to something similar to the following script:

```
names <- c("old.df", "new.df")

# use Date format
for (i in names) {
  i$Date <-  as.Date(i$Date, "%d/%m/%Y")
  i$Datetime <- as.Date(i$Datetime, "%d/%m/%Y %h:%m:%s.000")
  i$ClickDatetime <- as.Date(i$ClickDatetime, "%d/%m/%Y %h:%m:%s.000")
}
```

This actually doesn't work and returns the following error message:

```
Error in i$Date : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

I don't think I can use the `i` object in this way. I'm wondering if there is a nice workaround you usually use to achieve the same goal is similar conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Correct, it won't work like that because R sees `i` as the string, not the dataframe named by the string. Something like this should work:

```
df_list <- list(old_df, new_df)

# use Date format
for (df in df_list) {
  df["Date"] <-  as.Date(df["Date"], "%d/%m/%Y")
  df["Datetime"] <- as.Date(df["Datetime"], "%d/%m/%Y %h:%m:%s.000")
  df["ClickDatetime"] <- as.Date(df["ClickDatetime"], "%d/%m/%Y %h:%m:%s.000")
}

old_df <- df_list[[1]]
new_df <- df_list[[2]]
```

There are lots of ways to do this.
With only two dataframes, doing each one individually might be as good an option. With many dataframes with identical columns you could stack them up with `rbind` (putting in an identifier column to tell you which row belongs to which df), apply your changes and then split them apart again. Or put then in a list and build a function which can be used with `lapply`.